# Ошибка сохранения TDictionary

Tags: delphi

Почему в предоставленном коде:

Работает сохранения через: **SLOut.SaveToFile(new_name);**

И не работает через: **writeln(Fin2, S);**

**Задача:** Нужно что бы код работал через **writeln(Fin2, S);**

```
Var
  Fin, Fin2: TextFile;
  I, First: Integer;
  SLInS, S: String;
  SLIn, SLOut: TStringList;
  Dictionary: TDictionary<String, Integer>;
Begin
  // Тут открываю файл через
AssignFile(Fin, OpenDialog1.FileName);
reset(Fin);

// Тут сохраняю файл
AssignFile(Fin2, ExtractFileDir(OpenDialog1.FileName) + '\SAve.txt');
rewrite(Fin2);

Dictionary := TDictionary<String>.Create;
SLOut := TStringList.Create;
SLIn := TStringList.Create;
while not EOF(Fin) do
begin
  readln(Fin, S);
  SLIn.Add(S); { while }
end;

SLIn.Delimiter := '=';
SLIn.DelimitedText := SLIn.Text;

For I := 0 to SLIn.Count - 1 do
Begin
  SLInS := SLIn.Strings[I];
  if Pos('>', SLInS) <> 0 Then
    delete(SLInS, 1, Pos('>', SLInS));

  If Dictionary.ContainsKey(SLInS) = true then
    Dictionary[SLInS] := Dictionary[SLInS] + 2
  Else
    Dictionary.Add(SLInS, 2);
End;

for S in Dictionary.Keys do
  if Dictionary[S] > 1 then
    SLOut.Add(S + ' - ' + IntToStr(Dictionary[S]));
SLOut.CustomSort(MySort);
end;

 writeln(Fin2, SLOut.Text);

Dictionary.Free;
SLIn.Free;
SLOut.Free;
CloseFile(Fin);
CloseFile(Fin2);
```

Comment: а где закрытие файла?

Comment: "// Не работает!" - ??

Comment: @Igor, Именно в таком варианте не работает, то есть - writeln(Fin2, S);

Comment: @Денис Что значит "не работает", что происходит/не происходит?

Comment: @Igor, Не создается файл, вообще когда пишу writeln(Fin2, S);. А когда пишу SLOut.SaveToFile('save.txt'); то создается. Но нужно что бы код работал то через  writeln(Fin2, S);

Comment: @Денис "Не создается файл, вообще" - хм, в это трудно поверить. Вы видите, что Вы создаете его **не** в том же месте, куда пишет `SLOut.SaveToFile('save.txt');`?

Comment: @Igor, но я же сохраняю его там где расположенный файл который я открываю для чтения, то есть вот: ExtractFileDir(OpenDialog1.FileName) + '\SAve.txt');

Comment: @Денис Не торопитесь, перечитайте мой предыдущий комментарий.

Comment: @Igor, Ну я пробовал его в прописывать после SLIn.Add(S); Но тоже самое, ох я глуплю но не пойму где.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что будет в переменной `S` после окончания цикла?

```
WriteLn(Fin2, SLOut.Text);
```

Comment: Так тоже сделал, но все равно не создается файл. Я код обновил, оцените, по возможности, где я допускаю ошибку?

Comment: Когда Вы делаете `SLOut.SaveToFile(ExtractFileDir(OpenDialog1.FileName) + '\SAve.txt');`, файл пишется?

Comment: ВСЕ, 1000 извинений за свою неопытность. Оказывается, у меня: на запись был ExtractFileDir(OpenDialog1.FileName) а на открытие OpenDialog2.FileName. В этом то и было ошибка. А нужно было что бы OpenDialog1.FileName - Был одинаковый. то есть, номер. Благодаря Вам решил задачу. Всех благ и еще раз спасибо!